# Making a basic node javascript app to post on facebook timeline from a local webserver in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express

Hello I am currently a bit stuck on this. It seems to work but nothing posts to my timeline. I have made an app.js webserver in node and express:

```
var http = require('http'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

var app = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var index = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
  if(request.url === '/' || request.url === '/index.html') {
    fs.readFile(index, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('500 server error');
      } else {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end(data);
      }
    })
  } else if(request.url === '/jquery-1.11.3.js' ) {
    fs.readFile('jquery-1.11.3.js', function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('500 server error');
      } else {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end(data);
      }
    })
  } else {
    console.log('resource not found: ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end('<html><body>404 not found</body>');
  }
});

app.listen(8080, 'localhost');
console.log('server up at localhost:8080');
```

My index file where I set it all up looks like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'my_app_id_is_here',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="publish_actions" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium"></div>

<div id="publishBtn" style="padding-top: 20px">Click me to publish a "picture" post to Facebook.</div>

<script>
$(document).on(
  'fbload',  //  <---- HERE'S OUR CUSTOM EVENT BEING LISTENED FOR
  function(){
    FB.login(function(){
      FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {picture: 'http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/59/6974484-cute-cat-smile.jpg'},
        function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response.error);
          } else {
             console.log(response);
          }
        });
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
  }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have registered my app on facebook and placed the app id into the code as well as registered the app to respond to localhost:8080. 
When I launch the webserver I can go to localhost:8080, see the button, click it, it will ask me to log in, then ask if i want to post. Unfortunately nothing actually posts. This worked inside of rell during testing but does not work from a local server. I am very new to this and the documentation seems pretty sparse if anyone could shed some light I would be very thankful. If I  need to clarify anything let me know I am just trying to learn.

Comment: `picture` is supposed to be the thumbnail image of a link that gets posted. To use that parameter without using `link` as well doesn’t seem to make much sense.

Comment: Werd, thank you. I has started using 'message: "something"' but went to 'picture: "url"' because it worked in the rell editor. I will eventually go back and make this more proper. For now I am just trying to get it to post any6thing on my timeline.

Comment: What is the response you are seeing in your console?